Proof of formula of distance between skew lines
I reckon you saw the formula of distance between skew lines, $d = \frac{\left| (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}) \cdot (\mathbf{r}_2 - \mathbf{r}_1) \right|}{\|\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}\|}$, where $\mathbf{r}_1, \mathbf{r}_2 \text{:position vectors of points on the lines;} \\
\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \text{:direction vectors of the lines.}$
So, in the numerator, this is objectively the formula for the mixed product, while in the denominator, it is the formula for the vector cross product.
Question:
How exactly did the vector cross product and the scalar triple product end up here? Quite unexpectedly: the box volume divided by the normal vector! Can you give a full clarification and explanation?

Why are you writing both $[a,b]$ and $a\times b$ for the same thing? Anyhow, think about projection onto the cross product, not scalar triple product.

Don't start by telling us what "everyone" knows or has seen

$a\times b$ only means something in three dimensions. Are you restricting this question to that?

yes, i talking only about 3D, as I don’t know other dimensions, or you meant other

The vector product is normal to both $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.
Geometrically, you can think of two parallel planes $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ that have $\vec{a} \times \vec{b}$ as normal.
I always like to talk about a "projection" that is not what usually people call "projection". It is simpler: (it is just a "signed" size of the projection)
\begin{equation*}
  P_{\vec{d}}(\vec{v}) = \|\vec{v}\| \cos \theta,
\end{equation*}
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{d}$ and $\vec{v}$. This is actually given by the formula
\begin{equation*}
  P_{\vec{d}}(\vec{v}) = \vec{v} \cdot \frac{\vec{w}}{\|\vec{w}\|}.
\end{equation*}
That is, to "project" all you have to do is make the dot product with a unitary vector.
So, the distance you want is the absolute value of the "projection" (not a vector, just a number) of $\vec{r}_2 - \vec{r}_1$ to this normal direction. Notice that $\vec{r}_2 - \vec{r}_1$ is a vector "departing" from one plane to the other. And you don't want the sign. So, what you are looking for is the absolute value of:
\begin{equation*}
  P_{\vec{a} \times \vec{b}}(\vec{r}_2 - \vec{r}_1)
  =
  (\vec{r}_2 - \vec{r}_1) \cdot \frac{\vec{a} \times \vec{b}}{\|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}\|}.
\end{equation*}

A way to think about the geometric meaning of this formula is through the so called mixed product (at least, in Portuguese it is called something like that):
\begin{equation*}
\det(\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}) = (\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) \cdot \vec{c}.
\end{equation*}
I am going to suppose you know this mixed product and the fact that the determinant is a "signed volume". That is, if you take its absolute value, it is the volume of the parallelepiped determined by those three vectors.
Notice that there are two parallel planes, one containing one line and the other containing the other line.
For $\vec{c} = \vec{r}_2 - \vec{r}_1$, think of the parallelepiped with base in one of the planes. The base is the parallelogram determined by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. What you want to know is the "height" of this parallelepiped. That is, $\frac{\text{volume}}{\text{base area}}$.
If you know that the area of the parallelogram is $\|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}\|$, then you know the "height":
\begin{equation*}
  \text{height} = \frac{|\det(\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c})|}{\|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}\|} = \frac{|(\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) \cdot \vec{c}|}{\|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}\|}.
\end{equation*}

In two dimensions, the area of a parallelogram is the base multiplied by the perpendicular height.
Similarly, in three dimensions, the volume of a parallelopiped (the 3D-analogue of a parallelogram) is the base area multiplied by the perpendicular height.  The volume is the triple-scalar product (your numerator) and the base area is the (magnitude) of vector product.  Hence your formula.
Perhaps the hardest aspect of this is understanding why the triple-scalar product should give the volume at all.
